# Finding whether or not an item is contained within an k-ary tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I have a data type

```
data KTree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a [KTree a] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I would like to write a function that returns either true or false as to whether an item is contained within my tree.

```
ktreeContains :: Eq a => a -> (KTree a) -> Bool
ktreeContains _ Empty = False
ktreeContains y (Leaf x) = (x==y)
-- code for nodes goes here
```

So I realise I need to find whether the node itself is the item and then recursively call ktreeContains for the nodes children but I don't understand how to do this because each node can have many children.

I think the code I have so far is right, but feel free to correct me if not.

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
ktreeContains y (Node x ts) = x == y || any (ktreeContains y) ts
```

Just out of interest, what's the difference between `Leaf x` and `Node x []`?

Comment: The first has no children, and the other has zero children. But srsly `Leaf` can represent a complete solution in a search-tree, which by its nature has no ways to resume, and a `Node` may represent a partial solution, and having zero children means that either there is no way to resume or there were ways that were pruned.

Answer (score 2):

```
ktreeContains y (Node x ts) = x == y || (any . ktreeContains) y ts
```

Comment: There should be (ktreeContains y) in the first argument of map.

Comment: It should be `any (ktreeContains y) ts`

Comment: Maybe editing the answer would be a better idea than adding comments that make no sense after the answer has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored so I decided to generalise the solution using the `Data.Foldable` typeclass.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable hiding (any)

data KTree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a [KTree a] deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

ktreeContains :: Eq a => a -> (KTree a) -> Bool
ktreeContains _ Empty = False
ktreeContains y (Leaf x) = (x==y)
-- code for nodes goes here
ktreeContains y (Node x ts) = x == y || any (ktreeContains y) ts

example1 = Empty
example2 = Leaf 1
example3 = Node 1 [Leaf 2]
example4 = Node 2 [Leaf 1, Node 4 [Leaf 5, Leaf 3]]

ktreeContainsF :: Eq a => a -> KTree a -> Bool
ktreeContainsF y = getAny . foldMap (Any.(==y))

instance Foldable KTree where
    foldMap f (Empty) = mempty
    foldMap f (Leaf a) = f a
    -- work out a possible ordering thats better than this
    -- it works for now since we are only dealing with Equality
    foldMap f (Node a x) = f a `mappend` (mconcat . map (foldMap f)) x
```

`ktreeContains` and `ktreeContainsF` are identical functions except that in the `ktreeContainsF` the traversal of the `KTree` is handled by the `Data.Foldable` class.  Since `foldMap` returns a `Monoid` it's possible to use the `Any` monoid to combine the search results.

---

If it helps to understand this a bit better, `ktreeContainsF` is a more generalised version of `ktreeContainsMonoid` which is defined as

```
ktreeContainsMonoid y = getAny . Data.Foldable.foldl
        -- combination function, implicit when using FoldMap
        (\z x-> z `mappend` Any (x == y)) mempty -- also implicit in foldMap
```